# composer.json correct structure for multiple PHP packages

Tags: php, composer-php

I got this `composer.json` to install/update packages and I know its structure isn't correct:

```
{
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "d/sdk/paypal/"
  },
  "require": {
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*"
  },
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "d/sdk/push/"
  },
  "require": {
    "minishlink/web-push": "*"
  },
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "d/sdk/phpmailer/"
  },
  "require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0"
  }
}
```

can someone please show me correct structure? All I can find is examples for one single package. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This isn't very clear. There's only [one _schema_](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#json-schema) for composer.json files and a composer.json file can only correlate to a single composer project. What are you trying to achieve here? Could you [edit] your question?

Comment: So the whole composer crap is only for one package??? What's the point of composer then??? I thought it exists to install and UPDATE multiple packages with one command????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/)? Setting up your `composer.json` is very simple, next time please read the documentation before posting a question.

```
{
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "d/sdk"
  },
  "require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0",
    "minishlink/web-push": "*",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*"
  }
}
```

You don't need to specify a `vendor-dir`, as it will automatically create a `vendor` directory and save all your dependencies there.

Comment: I already seen the docs, so defining the dir for each package is just impossible, ok then

Comment: You did not specify in your post that "defining the dir for each package" is your actual question. But indeed I believe that is not possible.